# What does the error 'invalid class “DMNGroup” object' mean, how to resolve the problem?

Tags: r, error-handling, multiprocessing, dirichlet

I am trying to replicate the workflow from `library(DirichletMultinomial)`. I have large matrix containing counts `count` and vector of factors `pheno`. I made a subset of `count` into `countp` based on `pheno` (division into groups) as in the example in vignettes shows `countp <- count[pheno %in% c("group1", "group2"), ]` after executing the next step for Dirichlet-multinominal model for each group:

`bestgrp <- dmngroup(countp, pheno, k=1:15, simplify = FALSE, verbose=TRUE, .lapply = parallel::mclapply)`

the process was working for 8-12 hours and crashed reporting:

`invalid class “DMNGroup” object: undefined class for slot "elementMetadata" ("DataTable_OR_NULL")`

I know for sure that the process took several hours since crashed because I have following code

```
if(exists('bestgrp')) {
  save(bestgrp, file = "NRR_DMM_bestgrp.Rda")
} else {
  write(geterrmessage(), file = "!!!ERROR.txt") }
```

and have the time the error message was saved. Since `verbose=TRUE` doesn't work in parallel multiple core computing I don't have more specific point when it crashed. The whole dataset `count` when processed with `dmn` goes smooth.
I am not a bioinformatician, and new in R computing therefore as Google returns NULL results for the error message I am totally lost.
Can anyone help?
Best regards, Marcin

Answer (score 0):

I have updated Bioconductor to version 3.12 for R version 4.0.3 I am using. Now it works. For similar problems check support.bioconductor.org/p/92281